# 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any>' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

- I am running "yarn build" and/or "npm run build" on a repository. (same error for both commands)
- I am trying to build and deploy this code to an AWS environment so right now I am simply trying to get past the errors that tell me "failed to compile"
- The error is pointing to only one point in the whole app.
  This line :
  getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)

Here is the full error;

Type error: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any>' is not a valid JSX element.

```
                     <Loader />
                   ) : (
                     getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
                                ^
                   )
                 }
               </AuthConsumer>
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.

I have read similar questions and posts about this "component cannot be used as a JSX component" and they have not helped me on my quest to move forward.

Versions:
react, 
@types/react, 
@types/react-dom,
all set to version 17.0.2

I have deleted the package-lock.json files and left only the yarn-lock.json files for now

What clue am I missing to solve this puzzle?

kind regards

////////////// *I will add more code now below for others to see*

So the solution to this problem for me was adding these lines of code inside of my tsconfig.json file in compilerOptions...

`"paths": { "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ] }`

Below I will share the full code where the problem was coming from.

```js
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';

import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Router from 'next/router';
import nProgress from 'nprogress';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
import ThemeProvider from 'src/theme/ThemeProvider';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import createEmotionCache from 'src/createEmotionCache';
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { SidebarProvider } from 'src/contexts/SidebarContext';
import 'src/utils/chart';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from 'src/store';
import Loader from 'src/components/Loader';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import useScrollTop from 'src/hooks/useScrollTop';
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';
import { AuthConsumer, AuthProvider } from 'src/contexts/JWTAuthContext';

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
}

function MyApp(props: MyAppProps) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  useScrollTop();

  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', nProgress.start);
  Router.events.on('routeChangeError', nProgress.done);
  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', nProgress.done);

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <title>Tokyo White NextJS Typescript Admin Dashboard</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
      </Head>
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <SidebarProvider>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <AuthProvider>
                <SnackbarProvider
                  maxSnack={6}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'bottom',
                    horizontal: 'right'
                  }}
                >
                  <CssBaseline />
                  <AuthConsumer>
                    {(auth) =>
                      !auth.isInitialized ? (
                        <Loader />
                      ) : (
                        getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
                      )
                    }
                  </AuthConsumer>
                </SnackbarProvider>
              </AuthProvider>
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </SidebarProvider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

Comment: What is `Component`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share the code for  `Component` as well as the `getLayout` one

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Issue is with Latest Version of @types/react:18.x.x
This may have been introduced to your project via some other packages' peer dependency.

If you have a .tsconfig file, Add following to compilerOptions:

```
"paths": {
   "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Rkataria that is the solution to my error.

Now I am presented with a new error. It makes sense to me that the Latest Version of React is causing these issues, as I have read more about similar problems from other people. I will add to this question with more code for others to see. Let me know if you have further ideas.

Comment: This is indeed the solution. Thanks

Comment: You saved me from a huge headache, thank you! Could you explain why this snippet addition to .tsconfig fixes the errors?